# MS Edge outline artifact on focus blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I've got a vertical series of `<a>` elements in a simple popover menu. For a11y, I've wired up keyboard events and I'm using jQuery to focus() the `<a>`'s. The `<a>`'s are rendered by React, but their handlers are attached via jQuery. Some of the css defines an `<a>` focus style with a 2px outline. *Only in MS Edge,* when I move focus the previously focused `<a>` has a single horizontal 1px artifact line, as wide as the `<a>`. Moving focus to a lower/next `<a>` causes the artifact to appear on *top* of the previously focused `<a>`, moving focus to a higher/previous `<a>` causes the artifact to appear *below* the `<a>`. I've used Edge's developer panel to apply the pseudo-classes and set various outline rules on the affected `<a>` - the artifact is still there. These `<a>`'s also have border:0. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post enough code (include the related html and CSS style) or create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem? It is better to capture the screenshot to explain more detail about your issue, it might be easier us to help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Besides, which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Zhi. I'm going to trace back through the CSS libraries that are interacting to see if I can isolate the issue. I'll start with disabling the rules applied to links then add them back one-by-one. Might be a pseudo-class order issue, or some weird "edge case"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had applied a line-height rule to the div that contains the unordered list with the links. When I disabled that rule, no more artifacts. I'm going to leave it at that ... I'm not sure what interaction / spacing rules interoperated but since the issue is resolved, that's that.